# String to Int conversion in python

Tags: python, string, integer

If I have a string "2+3", is there anyway to convert it to an integer so it comes out as 5?

I tried this:

```
string = 2+3
answer = int(string)
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2+3'
```

I'm trying to take a fully parenthesized equation and use stacks to answer it.

ex. Equation = ((2+3) - (4*1))

I tried taking the equation as an input, but python just solves it on its own.
So to avoid that problem, I took the equation as a raw_input.

Comment: ummm, converting to postfix then evaluating?...

Comment: `eval` is actually a function that does exactly this!

Comment: oh I didn't even know that existed, thank you! It works now.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way, `eval` function..

```
>>> x = raw_input()
2 + 6
>>> x
'2 + 6'
>>> eval(x)
8
```

But be sure to verify that the input only has numbers,and symbols.

```
>>> def verify(x):
    for i in x:
        if i not in '1234567890.+-/*%( )':
            return False
    return True

>>> x = raw_input()
2 + 6
>>> x
'2 + 6'
>>> if verify(x):
    print eval(x)
8
```

`ast.literal_eval` doesn't work:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('2+3')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval('2+3')
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) (and remember to sanitize your input. More on this if you read the docs):

```
>>> eval('2+3')
5
```

It even supports variables:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> eval('x+1')
2
```

Comment: If the input comes from the user you should not use eval

Comment: Everyone knows that eval is not safe to use if you get user input, because it is executing arbitrary code. He should at least sanitize the input if he uses it.

Comment: (@Keyser) I know your answer works, not arguing that, just don't want to teach someone who might be a beginner bad habits

Comment: Yeah, probably [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would be a safer choice, since it only considers a small subset of Python's syntax to be valid.

Comment: whether you should use `eval()` with user input depends on if you *trust* the user.  Often, you do; but still need to protect the user from accidentally executing code on their behalf from a third party your user does not trust.